# How to get data with then from promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new with promises, and am stuck. I want to get data in the last then, and return a promise, cause i'm writing a function, that I'll use in some cases and do different stuff with returned data.

I want to return LAST `.then((user) => Promise.resolve({ user, userObject }))` as it is, to use it with then in places where I'll use function, but now I'm not ending with that statement, in case I'm loosing data in first .then statement. What's wrong?

UPDATE:

so here is the full function body. Now im using it like that:

```
signUpUser({ credentials: preparedForm })
  .then((t) => console.log('submitHandler -> t', t))
  .catch((e) => {
    handleSignUpErrors({
      form: signUpForm,
      updateForm: setSignUpForm,
      error: e,
      showErrors: setShowErrors,
    })
  })
```

But i'm not getting console.log. What's wrong?

```
const signUpUser = ({ credentials }) => {
  const {
    name,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    phone,
    emailVerified,
    phoneVerified,
  } = credentials

  const userObject = getUserObject({
    name,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    phone,
    emailVerified,
    phoneVerified,
  })

  return firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((data) =>
      db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(data.user.uid)
        .set(userObject)
        .then(() => data)
    )
    .then((user) => ({ user, userObject }))
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Promise.resolve` here. `.then` always returns a promise that resolve to the return value of the callback. But I'm not quite understanding what your problem really is.

Comment: i want to get in console.log 't' object with {user, userObject}

Comment: Can you try using async/await. That might be the issue

Comment: yes i can use it, but i'd want to find solution with then:)

Comment: What you have seems right to me. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Promise resolve` at all, just return all objects in `.then`, this should work for you.

```
  const userObject = getUserObject({
    name,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    phone,
    emailVerified,
    phoneVerified,
  })

  return firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((data) =>
      return db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(data.user.uid)
        .set(userObject)
        .then(() => data)
    )
    .then((user) => ({ user, userObject }))
```

Comment: I'v updated my post to get full picture, where and how i want to use data from returned function signUpUser. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
const userObject = getUserObject({
  name,
  lastName,
  email,
  password,
  phone,
  emailVerified,
  phoneVerified,
})

return firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((data) =>
    db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(data.user.uid)
    .set(userObject)
    .then(response => response)
  )
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: thats wrong. please check my question and update how and what i want to have as a result from function

Comment: Code only answers are often not helpful. Could you add an explanation on why/how your code fixes the problem in the question?